# Projective representation (Z/2Z)^2

Tags: representation-theory

I'm not used to projective representations, I guess my question (if well-asked) is trivial.

I have a representation of any $x\in (Z/2Z)^2$ into $U_x\in U_2$ (a complex unitary matrix of dimension 2).
I think this is called a projective representation? What can I say, how can I write it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer can be found here, in case someone find this useful:
https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_representation_theory_of_Klein_four-group